# Export large csv format data from R

Tags: r, csv

I exported very large csv format data via R, but since the the maximum raw of excel is 10480, I had to split it into several csv files in order to export it as csv, it's very inconvenient to handle them after that, is there any apropos way to export nearly 10 times of 10480 raw csv in just one file at the same time via R?

Thank you very much.

Comment: This sounds like an Excel problem, not an R problem. A CSV is nothing other than a text file, and Excel is just one way to view it

Comment: What do you want to do with the data after it's exported?

Comment: I have dealt with .csv files that are 30+ GB and tens of millions of rows. I second @rsoren that this is a problem with Excel.

Comment: To add to what @rsoren said, Excel does have a row limit but that is on what it can display. If you export the data as a csv, it is all there but excel can't view it all. If you open that same file in a different program (like notepad) you will be able to see all of your data. But when you export it from r, all of the data is there. You don't need to split files.

Answer (score 0):

If you must use Excel with the data, you can keep the huge csv files and query them from within Excel. You could alternatively start building a database with the csv files and query the database from within Excel. This link might help you.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-Microsoft-Query-to-retrieve-external-data-42a2ea18-44d9-40b3-9c38-4c62f252da2e